Strange word-break: break-all behavior in Chrome
Consider the following div


div {
  width: 310px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: monospace;
}
<div>
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa:::::::::::::::::\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>



In Firefox it looks as expected, with lines breaking after every 44 characters:

However, in Chrome it looks like this instead:

Why does Chrome give special meaning to colons and backslashes in plain text? And how do I make it break lines evenly instead?

The \ doesn’t seem relevant. In tests I found that the weird break occurred when the number of colons was such that the line became too long. It looks as though the system then thought ‘aha, I’d better go back to find a sensible break point’, but it gets that wrong by a character. Seen on Chrome and Safari. Looks like a bug.

It seems Chrome and Firefox don't agree on where word-break: break-all; should place the soft wrap opportunities. Specifically around what should be considered a punctuation character.
The word-break spec does mention for break-word

NOTE: This value does not affect whether there are soft wrap opportunities around punctuation characters. To allow breaks anywhere, see line-break: anywhere.

Adding line-break: anywhere should show the same behavior for both, breaking exactly at the between '\' and 'a'


div {
  line-break: anywhere;

  width: 310px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
}
<div>
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa::::::::::::::::\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>



I had to add a bunch of colons to make the snipit reproduce, might be related to a difference in zoom/resolution settings
